# Unchecking of checkbox should remove appended html but

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

quick question, how to fix js code to remove text content from ul.results after checkbox has been unchecked. Strangely enough if the text is all simple letters or numbers the text is removed upon unchecking of the box, but text with  or whatever parentheses the text does not get removed upon unchecking of the checkbox. I'm a newb as you can most certainly see so please be gentle with me and js fiddle would be the best option for an answer, love that jsfiddle. Here is the [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ek2zh/151/) of what I'm asking a solution for.

```
<div class="box-checkbox-color">

        <input type="checkbox" name="Color:_Green"  id="sku0001-green" value="Yes" />
        <label for="sku0001-green"></label>
    <div style="display:none;" title="#" class="rawHTML-code-insert">ggg<b>THIS ONE NOT GETTING REMOVED with uncheck</b>ggg</div>
    </div>


<div class="box-checkbox-color">

        <input type="checkbox" name="Color:_Green2"  id="sku0001-green2" value="Yes" />
        <label for="sku0001-green2"></label>
        <div style="display:none;" title="#" class="rawHTML-code-insert">THIS ONE DOES???</div>
    </div>


<ul class="result"></ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    var title = $(this).closest('.box-checkbox-color').find('.rawHTML-code-insert').html();
    // If the checkbox is checked, add the item to the ul.
    if($(this).attr('checked')){
        var html = $("<li/>", {
            title: title,
            text: title
        });
        $('ul.result').append(html);
    } else {     
        // if the checkbox is unchecked, remove the item from the ul.
        $('li[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. http://jsfiddle.net/ek2zh/154/

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    var title = $(this).closest('.box-checkbox-color').find('.rawHTML-code-insert').html();
    var tempId = $(this).attr('id');

    // If the checkbox is checked, add the item to the ul.
    if($(this).attr('checked')){
        var html = $("<li/>", {
            title: title,
            idholder: tempId,
            text: title
        });
        $('ul.result').append(html);
    } else {     
        // if the checkbox is unchecked, remove the item from the ul.
        $('[idholder="' + tempId + '"]','ul').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: because i am a fool, jus kidding. That works great, thank you deeply. Clearly everyone here is smarter than I am, haha.

Comment: I edited my post to reflect each checkbox operating independently. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

check below Code

**HTML**

```
<div class="box-checkbox-color">

        <input type="checkbox" name="Color:_Green"  id="sku0001-green" value="Yes" />
        <label for="sku0001-green"></label>
        <div style="display:none;" title="#" class="rawHTML-code-insert">&lt;div class="box-checkbox-color"&gt;

        &lt;input type="checkbox" name="Color:_Green"  id="sku0001-green" value="Yes" /&gt;
        &lt;label for="sku0001-green"&gt;&lt;/label&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;</div>
    </div>


<div class="box-checkbox-color">

        <input type="checkbox" name="Color:_Green2"  id="sku0001-green2" value="Yes" />
        <label for="sku0001-green2"></label>
        <div style="display:none;" title="#" class="rawHTML-code-insert">&lt;div class="box-checkbox-color"&gt;

        &lt;input type="checkbox" name="Color:_Green"  id="sku0001-green" value="Yes" /&gt;
        &lt;label for="sku0001-green"&gt;&lt;/label&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;</div>
    </div>


<ul class="result"></ul>
```

**JS**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    var title = $(this).closest('.box-checkbox-color').find('.rawHTML-code-insert').html();
    // If the checkbox is checked, add the item to the ul.
    if($(this).attr('checked')){
        var html = '<li title="' + title + '">' + title + '</li>';
        $('ul.result').append(html);
    } else {     
         var html = '';
        $('ul.result').html(html);
    }

});
```

Click here [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ek2zh/149/)